# Fragment Cache a user control in asp.net webform Masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, infragistics, outputcache

I had a Masterpage which uses as sidebar for navigation .I created a user control for that sidebar  as each user will have their own set of navigation menus.

Inside my UserMenu I use Infragistic webexplorer and Iam creating each item  of webexplorer using ado.net result from database dynamically.

Everything is working fine .in high bandwidth but in low bandwidth it takes 3-4 seconds for the menubar to load.causing users to wait so much on each postback.

So I tried fragment caching .but i seems not working.can you suggest me whats wrong

In masterpage I did

```
    <div>
    //this is my usercontrol
                         <uc1:DynamicMenuBar runat="server" id="DynamicMenuBar" />
    </div>      
     <div id="main" class="content" >

       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    <div class="bodybackground">
                    </div>

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
```

In my usercontrol .ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DynamicMenuBar.ascx.cs" Inherits="ArtWebApp.DynamicMenuBar" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Infragistics35.Web.v12.1, Version=12.1.20121.2236, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb" namespace="Infragistics.Web.UI.NavigationControls" tagprefix="ig" %>
<%@ OutputCache Duration="600" VaryByParam="none" %>
<ig:WebExplorerBar ID="WebExplorerBar1" runat="server" Width="250px">
</ig:WebExplorerBar>
```

And in my usercontrol .ascx.cs I had done the below

```
   public partial class DynamicMenuBar : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                loadexplorerebar(); //this function creates the groups and childs based on the database result dynamically
                this.WebExplorerBar1.EnableViewState = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Page_Load will still be called even if the uc is cached.  Try checking to see if it's in the cache before calling loadexplorerebar().  It'll be null if it's not in the cache.

So try changing:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
```

to:

```
if (!IsPostBack && WebExplorerBar1 == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the internet problem. Try using AJAX call instead of server code for menu retrieval